# How do I find y' in this problem?

Tags: calculus

$$y^3 = cos(xy)   $$
This is what I have so far:
$$(3y^2y'/y+xy') = -sin(xy)*y    $$
$$ y' = -sin(xy) (3y^2/y)$$

I'm sure I did the last part wrong, but that was the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see where your second line comes from, but the derivative of $y^3$ with respect to $x$ is by the chain rule $3y^2y'$, the right hand side gives 
$$ -\sin(xy) \cdot (xy)' = -\sin(xy)\cdot (y + xy') $$
also by the chainrule
so we have
\begin{align*}
  3y^2y' &= -\sin(xy)(y+xy')\\
\iff y'(3y^2 + x\sin(xy) &= -y\sin(xy)\\
  \iff y' &= -\frac{y\sin(xy)}{3y^2 + x\sin(xy)} 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$3 y^2 y' = -\sin{(x y)} (y+x y')$$

implies that

$$(3 y^2 + x \sin{(x y)} ) y' = -y \sin{(x y)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d(y^3}{dx}=\frac{dcos(xy)}{dx}$

$\Rightarrow 3y^2y'=-sin(xy)y-xsin(xy)y'$

$\Rightarrow (3y^2+x sin(xy))y'=-ysin(xy)$

$\Rightarrow y'=\frac{-ysin(xy)}{x sin(xy)+3y^2}$